# How to find Primefaces editor element ID or Xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-rc

[Editor](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/editor.xhtml) -Its the link for Primefaces editor. I am trying to find element id or xpath, but I can't. Kindly help me. Screen Shot attached

[image]

Comment: Just thought I would mention for next time: screenshots, for the most part, are useless. A link to a webpage, like http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/editor.xhtml , is much more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the element you're trying to interact with is inside of an `<iframe>`.  Selenium can only access elements in the current frame.  You can switch to the `<iframe>` as follows:

```
WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys("Text!");
```

When you're finished in the `<iframe>`, you can switch back out using `defaultContent()`:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```